# The trace of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with complex eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ is...

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following theorem in my book:

Consider an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with complex eigenvalues $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$, listed with their algebraic multiplicities. Then:

$$\operatorname{tr} A = \lambda_1 +...+\lambda_n$$

I'm trying to prove the theorem, but I don't know if the proof for real eigenvalues follows the same as it does for complex eigenvalues.

$A = SBS^{-1}$, where $B$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A$, and $S$ is a matrix with columns that are the eigenvectors of $A$.

$$\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(SBS^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr}(BSS^{-1}) = \operatorname{tr}(B) = \lambda_1+...+\lambda_n$$

Is this an adequate proof of the theorem?

Comment: Are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n$ different? Then if so your factorization exists (this is sufficient). Have you heard of the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @Sudarsan I don't think $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ are necessarily unique, but I haven't heard of Jordan canonical form.

Comment: What book is this? If I may ask so as to view the setting of this theorem.

Comment: The theorem also says "listed with algebraic multiplicities". Where are the algebraic multiplicities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have proven that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, and you have shown that matrices can be Jordan decomposed, then your proof is correct.

But it may be easier to work directly with the characteristic polynomial. Look at
$$\det(A-\lambda I)$$
and in particular, at its $(n-1)$st order term.

What can you say about it in terms of the trace of $A$? (If you need a hint to get started, try expanding by minors along the first row. What can you say about the maximum degree in $\lambda$ of all cofactors except the first?)

What can you say about it in terms of the roots of the characteristic polynomial?